# Betrayal at house on the hill #43 the star-sickness

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

When you die as an explorer but are also a traitor, and are transitioning into an alien, do you still trade monster tokens to spread the trader infection?   The trader died from the person who initiated the haunt during their additional roll that damages everyone if the can't defend the attacks.

The rules do not specifically say but we have argued that the traitor explorer has the alien virus already so isn't really alive to begin with, and you don't drop your items until the next turn after they miss their turn (from dying and going into transition). So it could go either way that you can trade monster tokens or not.

Answer (score 1):

## Spoilers Ahead

#### Turn back now...

Here's my interpretation based on the haunt rules.

It's never stated that the traitor is dead nor does it sound like the traitor is the real enemy it's just one of your party has an alien infection and may be turning into an otherworldly specimen.

> Ever since I touched that meteorite, I can feel the change working in
>  me... If I do not succeed [creating an antidote], perhaps these notes will help whoever comes after. I pray, though, that this disease will die with me.

Personally, if someone dies during the attack against explorers immune system I would think that the explorer is no longer an explorer but in a transitioning state. The book says:

> If a traitor dies for any reason... a transformation to the third stage takes place. The **transforming traitor** skips their next turn.

Since the transforming traitor cannot do anything on their upcoming turn since they're in the process of transforming into the 3rd stage alien, I would assume they're no longer an explorer and would not be able to interact with any of the explorers in the house which includes trading monster tokens.

---

There's so many haunts that need clarification which unfortunately can't all be verified by the rulebooks. The last page of the rulebook states:

> What if there isn't a rule that for x scenario? In such cases, come to
>   an agreement as a group for what makes the most sense and go with it.

**The most important rule is to have fun!**